# Get the base array of an enumerated array

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to sort an array based on the value as well as the index of each element, so I'd like to do something like this:

```
let a = [4,9,5,7].enumerate()
let b = a.sort { ... }
```

But then I need to convert b back to an array without the indices. My current solution is

```
let c = b.map { $0.1 }
```

But I was wondering, if there's a simpler way, since b is of the type `EnumerateSequence<Array<Int>>` and has a property `base` which holds the array that I want. Unfortunately `base` is `internal` and I don't know if there is any method that returns what I want.

**Note:** You might have noticed that this is Swift 2. While I need a solution in Swift 2 (if there is any), I am of course interested if there's a difference between Swift 2 and Swift 3.

Comment: Are you sure that `b` is of type `EnumerateSequence`? `sort` returns an array, so after sorting the `EnumerateSequence` is irretrievably gone. Even if the `base` property were public, that wouldn't help you in this case.

Comment: Most interesting @OleBegemann. You are right, I somehow must have checked the type of the wrong instance. Thank you for that helpful hint.

Answer (score 0):

> But I was wondering, if there's a simpler way

No. `let c = b.map { $0.1 }` *is* simple.

Comment: Of course, one might question why you're going this at all. You surely don't _really_ need the enumerated index-value pairs in order to sort the array, do you? So why don't you just sort of array, plain and simple? What is the `enumerate` call for in the first place?

Comment: Like I said: I need to sort based on value and index, imagine `.sort{ $0%6 < $1%6 }` keeping the original order of elements where `$0%6 == $1%6` as an example.

Comment: Ok, simple was a poor choice of words on my part, what I meant is: Without traversing the whole array again. Yes, this is more out of curiosity than an actual need for better performance. After all, the values are right there.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly (*2 characters*) simpler:

```
let c = b.map { $1 }
```

`map` receives a tuple of two values, so you can either refer to the two values as `$0.0` and `$0.1`, or as `$0`, and `$1`.  When your closure uses only `$0`, then `$0` is the entire tuple, so `.0` and `.1` refers to the individual items.  When your closure mentions `$1`, then `$0` is the first item of the tuple and `$1` is the second item of the tuple.

Comment: This does work in Swift 2 and 3, but note that it will no longer work in Swift 4. The relevant Swift-Evolution proposal is [SE-0110](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md).

Comment: Thanks @OleBegemann.  Swift is ever the moving target because it isn't afraid to improve.